Average of non-negative integers using integer division

Statistics are often calculated with varying amounts of input data. Write a program that takes any number of non-negative integers as input, and outputs the average (using integer division) and max. A negative integer ends the input and is not included in the statistics.
Ex: When the input is:
15 20 0 5 -1

the output is:
10 20


Here is my code that keeps timing out. I know a lot of it is wrong. The other similar post followed a different format than I was learning.
integer positiveinput
integer Avg
integer sumValues
integer numValues
integer maxValues

positiveinput=Get next input
sumValues = 0
numValues = 0
maxValues = 0

while positiveinput > 0
  numValues = (numValues + 1)
  sumValues = (sumValues + positiveinput)
  Avg = (sumValues / numValues)
  if positiveinput > maxValues
    maxValues = positiveinput

Put Avg to output
Put " " to output
Put maxValues to output


Inside your while loop, you never request for the next input

integer positiveinput
integer Avg
integer sumValues
integer numValues
integer maxValues

positiveinput=Get next input
sumValues = 0
numValues = 0
maxValues = 0

while positiveinput > 0
  numValues = (numValues + 1)
  sumValues = (sumValues + positiveinput)
  if positiveinput > maxValues
    maxValues = positiveinput
  
  positiveinput=Get next input         <----- gets next input

Avg = (sumValues / numValues)          <-- evaluate at the end

Put Avg to output
Put " " to output
Put maxValues to output

Not sure about the formatting, but in terms of logic the average should be evaluated at the end, and the positive input should be updated with the next value on each loop iteration.
